# How do I wire up these two sconces?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, multiway-switch, circuit

I need some help to correctly rewire some sconces. The bedroom had these sconces missing for years and I am putting in new ones, but I am getting a tad confused on correctly wiring them back up. I'll explain what I see and have figured out, then explain what is throwing me in loop:

There is one switch for the whole room. That controls the ceiling light of course, and it should control the sconces I assume, unless they planned for sconces with switches on them. The first sconce box (sconce #1), has 3 sets of black and white. The second sconce box (sconce #2), only has two sets. I have the labeled the switch wire that comes from the ceiling light after confirming they go hot when the switch is turned on and ceiling light is on in the first sconce box with a basic circuit tester. The second set goes to an outlet immediately below the box, and the third set I assume goes to the next sconce.

The outlet below sconce #1 has only one pair of wires, that are seemingly coming straight down from sconce #1. Pretty straight forward.

Sconce #2's box only has two sets of black and whites, one set that is seemingly coming from sconce #1 and one set going to the outlet box below it.

The outlet box under sconce #2 has two sets of wires in it. One seemingly coming down from sconce #2 and one set that is completely on another circuit. (Confirmed by flipping the breaker and going dead when I do it)

So by my understanding, I have two seperate circuits meeting up in these 2 sconces. My goal is to make it so the outlets function on thier respective circuit, and be able to shut both sconces off with the ceiling light.

When I opened these sconce boxes, I found all black and white wires connected to eachother, except the switch wires in sconce #1, which were just capped off and shoved in the back.

Here is where I was thrown off:
When testing wires in sconce #1 while the wires in sconce #2 were still connected, I found the white from the switch pair, and the white from sconce #2 would show up as hot. This is with the light switch shut off *and* the outlet circuit breaker shut off as well. As soon as I undid the whites in sconce #2, it stopped showing up as hot in sconce #1.

I suppose my question is simply, how do I wire these up correctly so that outlets function on thier own circuit and all lights in the room shut off together without affecting outlets? Any help would be immensely appreciated.

I can provide more detail as needed.

Comment: Maybe it was roughed in for two options? Option 1: Operate the sconces with the ceiling's switch, in which case you ignore the power supply from the outlet boxes. Option 2: Operate the sconces with switching built into the sconces, in which case you ignore the power supply from the ceiling. For option 2 the wire from two outlet boxes instead of one was unnecessary, but maybe option 2 was implemented before the subsequent work enabling option 1?

Comment: Yeah I am guessing it was most likely roughed in for option 2 at this point. It would make sense, since those type of sconces were more common during the 70's, when I think this room was last worked on. So I'm guessing I would have to run either run a new wire from the powered outlet to the one below sconce #1 to keep those on a seperate circuit and wire up the sconces on the switches circuit, or get sconces with switches again?

Comment: So outlet #1 draws power from outlet #2 with a tortuous path through the sconces? That's one circuit. And there's therefore no cable to bridge the light circuit from sconce #1 into sconce #2? You need another cable to link the sconces, right? Sounds like the only work around is bridging outlet #1 and outlet #2 with a new cable or similarly bridging the sconce boxes with an additional cable. If the cable between sconce boxes isn't stapled, they you might be able to use the old cable to pull two new ones (or to fish a line through the wall that subsequently pulls the old cable and a new cable).

Comment: Well it seems the outlet #2 is getting power from outside the room and going up to the box for sconce #2 and then there is a wire going from sconce #2 box to sconce #1 box. Then that is where there is a wire going down to outlet #1. And for some reason they pulled the wire from the switch/ceiling light circuit into sconce #1's box but just capped that off. So I'm not really sure why they did that, and if it was somehow wired up to use the switches circuit. But as far as I understand, two circuits probably shouldn't meet? I might just add toggle switches on my new sconces.

Comment: It's easy to fish electrical cable vertically in a wall cavity. The horizontal part is hard. The sconces probably were originally wired through the ceiling light, but somebody stole the horizontal cable between boxes to facilitate the installation of outlet #1. Removing the sconces may go back to this same scope of work. You have to run an additional cable if you want your original ask.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sounds like that might have been the case. I think I'll just add toggle switches and call it day on that. Cheers and thank you again.